# GCP - Monitoring - Alerting - Policies - Documentation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert

I have create the alert policy from Logs-based Metrics to filter the ERROR level messages and send out the alert once got error. But from the email, I can see there's limited information and I want to customise the information such as add the error message in, etc.
I found if I want to add my customised info into the email, I can only use the Documentation in the alert policy configuration. But I have no idea how to configure the Documentation to get the messages I want.

Answer (score 0):

For the `alerting policy` related to a log based metric, the link to the log is proposed in the email content.

The link target to the concerned logs to `Cloud Logging`.

You can add the documentation of the policy to give details but I think you can’t directly add the error logs in the email content.

But, you have the link to the log and in this case the email receivers can have all the error details from Cloud Logging.